# How to work with Pagination in Delphi REST components

Tags: rest, delphi, pagination

Within Delphi Seattle, I am using the Delphi Rest components to retrieve data via REST services.  My data provider appears to limit results to 1000 rows at a time, meaning I need to use pagination.  I know a pagination URL is returned in the REST data stream.  So a couple questions...

(1) Do the Delphi components support a GetNextPage (or something similar?).  If so, I could not find it.

(2)  How do I retrieve the URL to get the next page?  Do I then update the TRESTRequest resource property and EXECUTE again?

(3).  I am using a RestResponseDataSetAdapter to access this data (via DataSource and ClientDataSet).  I am assuming that there is NO WAY to "combine" the data results from multiple REST calls.  For example, if I retrieve 1,000 rows via my first call, and 300 rows via the second call, there is no way to access all 1300 rows at the same time?

I have looked on Google, as well as REST documentation and did not find anything useful.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. Pagination is implemented quite differently depending on the server you're connecting to. There's no way these components could cover any and every possible scenario. You'll have to just follow the rules as provided by this service, and implement them in every request the way you need. I've never used two REST servers which followed the same rules as each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single standard way to implement pagination, as different Web/REST servers implement it in their own way. It's next to impossible for these components to have built-in pagination options covering any and every possible scenario.

Whatever service you're using should provide you details of how to implement pagination. Usually, this is part of the query string. For example...

```
http://someserver.com/someresource?pageSize=100&page=1
```

...or sometimes perhaps in the resource...

```
http://someserver.com/someresource/1/
```

...or sometimes in the HTTP headers...

```
Page-Size: 100
Page: 1
```

I've also seen some servers which provide a URL in their response, pre-defined and ready for you to use to navigate to the next page of results...

```
{
  "next_page": "http://someserver.com/someresource?pageSize=100&page=3",
  "prev_page": "http://someserver.com/someresource?pageSize=100&page=1"
}
```

But again, every server is different. I've never seen any two REST servers which follow the exact same rules as each other.

You will just have to read the rules as instructed by this service, and implement your pagination in each and every request, as you need.

---

That being said, whenever I write any sort of API wrapper, the first step is to establish a standard communication layer, which implements anything which is common across all requests available on that particular service. Here, I would add pagination options, working according to how that service was designed.

Comment: Fair enough.  I did resolve my issue.  The issue turned out to be that the service would stop sending data at 1,000 rows.  Subsequently, REST thought  it was done, but my data stream did not have anything there...